# Studying ASP .NET Core MVC I created a simple WEB service and request name by ID, but error when recuseting name by name

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, model-view-controller, controller

I am a beginner with ASP .NET core and C#.
I created a ASP .NET Core solution using MVC pattern. It is a simple webservice.
URL request http://localhost:5000/api/names/1 works fine.
Responding HttpGet action in controller is:

```
//Test on http://localhost:5000/api/names/1
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public Models.Name GetName(long ID,
            [FromServices] ILogger<NamesController> logger)
        {
            logger.LogDebug("GetName Action Invoked");
            return context.Names.Find(ID);
        }
```

If I try to change the action to be able to query for name instead of ID:

```
//Test på http://localhost:5000/api/names?givenname=Henrik
[HttpGet("{givenname}")]
public Models.Name GetGivenName(string GivenName,
    [FromServices] ILogger<NamesController> logger)
{
    logger.LogDebug("GetName Action Invoked");
    return context.Names.Find(GivenName);
}
```

I get error:
HTTP ERROR 405

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FromQuery] in the controller method to make it clear that's where the parameter is.

```
    [HttpGet()]
    public string GetGivenName([FromQuery]string givenName,
        [FromServices] ILogger<NamesController> logger)
    {
        return givenName;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to invoke the GivenName Action with a string parameter (givenname) however it is working with an int parameter(id) above.. That is why it is not being supported.

Either try use different methods for different value retrievals or may be change the type of these parameters to string (however, it won't be a good idea to do so).